# Why does collision only work when keys are being pressed?

Tags: unity, c#

My `player` object containing a `rigidbody` that is controlled using `Input`, is not colliding with an `enemy` unless keys are pressed. When no `keys` are pressed, the `enemy` simply goes through the `player` without `collision`. I'm using Unity 5.6.1f1.

I figured the problem is in the `Patrol` class because when I don't attach the script to the `enemy` object the `collision` appears to take place fine.
But I don't know what I'm doing wrong in this script because I seems to do it's task well. I wrote this script to make the `enemy` object move between points in `patrolPoints` which are just some `empty`'s in the game world.

So, I would like to know if I'm doing it right or is there another way to do it.

**Patrol.cs**

```
public class Patrol : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform[] patrolPoints;
    public float speed;
    private int currentPoint;
    private bool forward;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        transform.position = patrolPoints [0].position;
        currentPoint = 0;
        forward = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (transform.position == patrolPoints [currentPoint].position) {
            if (currentPoint < patrolPoints.Length - 1 && forward) {
                currentPoint++;
            } else {
                currentPoint--;
                forward = false;
            }

            if (currentPoint == 0)
                forward = true;
        }   

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, 
            patrolPoints [currentPoint].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used the default `Input` settings....

Comment: @Gnemlock I've added my codes..

Comment: You're sure you have no other behaviours running that might read keyboard?

Comment: yep I have only used `Input` for player control.

Comment: I just found out my enemy is not colliding with any thing..but my player object is colliding fine... what do you think am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do the enemies have colliders on them? Are they active?

Comment: The fact that we are having to enter into discussion like this points to why we require a [minimal, verifiable example of the problem](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/whats-a-minimum-complete-verifiable-example-mcve-and-how-do-i-provide-it) to consider [debugging questions ontopic](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/what-counts-as-a-debug-my-code-type-of-question).

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I have a `box-collider` to it and it's active I guess(It's checked in the Inspector).

Comment: @Gnemlock While you are correct in saying so, one must try to appreciate that users who come here with Unity problems cannot always provide all the information till they are asked for it... heck, it's hard even for users writing applications that are fully represented as text. Let alone where a lot of the data is by default stored as part of the project metadata.

Comment: @Gnemlock I'm good with it. Give it the old close-a-roo.

Comment: @Gnemlock that would be really helpful..

Comment: @Gnemlock I've updated my question plz look at it..

Comment: @ArcaneEngineer I've updated my question plz look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your bodies around using [Rigidbody.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html), by modifying [Rigidbody.velocity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) vector, or using [Rigidbody.MovePosition](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html). These should ensure that collisions continue to work, whereas your line

`transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, patrolPoints [currentPoint].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);`

will break collision functionality.